# Inserting B/W .jpg image causes image to be entirely black

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I am working with `.jpg` images that are all B/W. Here is an example image I am using:

[image: Sample image]

and here is what I am using to put the image into my document:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{1980image}
\caption[Sample Caption]{Sample Caption}
\end{figure}
```

However, when I run, the image becomes entirely black. Here is a screenshot from my document:

[image: All black image]

Has anyone seen this before? Changing the filetype to `.png` does not fix anything.

Comment: Do you have `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` in your file? This would explain the black image most probably

Comment: Thank you so much! Removing the `[demo]` fixed it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to a wrong package option

Comment: Strange, I did not see that question when I initially searched for it on this site. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Ryan: Well anyway, you have a nice question to answer yourself and possible earning the self-learner badge ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the line `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`. Removing the `[demo]` in this line fixed the problem.